# Access resource in nested model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

I have a nested model

```
resources :customer do
  resources :readings
end
```

Customers model has

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :phase_type, :readings_attributes
 has_many :readings
end
```

Readings Controller has

```
 class Reading < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :customer_id, :date_of_reading, :reading1, :reading2, :reading3
   belongs_to :customer
 end
```

I have written a helper method to determine how to render partials based on the phase_type in the customer's model however, the helper method is rendered in a form in the readings edit view.

The form in readings/_form_reading is

```
<%= simple_form_for [@reading.customer, @reading], :html => { :class => 'form- horizontal' } do |f| %>
<%= render "shared/error_messages", :target => @reading %>
<%= f.input :customer_id %>
<%= f.input :date_of_reading, :as => :date %>
<%= render_readings_conditionally(f) %>
<div class="form-actions">
  <%= f.button :submit, :class => 'btn-primary' %>
  <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
              customer_path, :class => 'btn' %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

The Render_readings_conditionally helper is

```
module ApplicationHelper
def render_readings_conditionally(form)
 if @customer.phase_type == 'Single Phase'
  render 'readings/single_phase',f: form
 else
  render 'readings/three_phase',f: form
 end 
 end
end
```

The problem i have is i need to determine the type of customer phase type in order to render partials unconditionally however, @customer.phase_type will not work because it is not in the readings model, how can i access it?

Comment: I hope those aren't your actual routes. Those aren't nested, despite the indentation; they're two separate top-level resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to do but maybe this will help in something.
routes.rb for nested resources should be like this:

```
resources :customers do
  resources :readings
end
```

If you want to access phase_type in @reading

```
@reading.customer.phase_type
```

[Rails nested resource guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#generating-a-controller)

Comment: You guessed right, I want to access the phase_type in @reading however, that answer you gave me returns an error 'undefined method phase_type'

Comment: this is full error text? or it is "undefined method phase_type for nil object"? Try to comment (#) attr_accessible in both models just to test if it's working without that.

Comment: It is good to go, I just had not saved in my text editor, thank you